# How to get the Dropzone.js return value?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, dropzone.js

I just implemented [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to make file uploads on my website easier. The file uploads fine, and after it finished uploading I give the file an id and return this id to the browser.

This works fine, except for that I don't know how to catch the id that gets returned from the server. In [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20113798/1650012) I found some code that should supposedly do that, but it doesn't work for me. The code I have now is pasted below.

Does anybody know how I can get the value that is returned by the server? All tips are welcome!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/external/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/static/css/external/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        Dropzone.options.uiDZResume = {
            success: function(file, response){
                console.log('WE NEVER REACH THIS POINT.');
                alert(response);
            }
        };
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="/doc"
      class="dropzone"
      id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looking at the source code of dropzone.js, it seems that there is a lot of events you can listen to.

```
events: [
  "drop"
  "dragstart"
  "dragend"
  "dragenter"
  "dragover"
  "dragleave"
  "addedfile"
  "removedfile"
  "thumbnail"
  "error"
  "errormultiple"
  "processing"
  "processingmultiple"
  "uploadprogress"
  "totaluploadprogress"
  "sending"
  "sendingmultiple"
  "success"
  "successmultiple"
  "canceled"
  "canceledmultiple"
  "complete"
  "completemultiple"
  "reset"
  "maxfilesexceeded"
  "maxfilesreached"
]
```

Here the "success" event seems to be appropriate.

A good starting point would be to bind an event listener to your dropzone and see what data you get on such event.

```
$('#my-awesome-dropzone').on('success', function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  // Look at the output in you browser console, if there is something interesting
  console.log(args);
});
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for that! Would you possibly have a little example code of how I might do that (my js skills aren't up to par with my php and Python skills)?

Comment: I tried this (including the `#my-awesome-dropzone`), but it doesn't work. The function simply never gets called. I tried binding to other events, such as `"drop"` (which works), `"dragenter"` (also works), `"success"` (doesn't work), `"complete"` (also doesn't work) and `"addedfile"` (also doesn't work). Would you have any idea why some are called and others not?

Comment: Due to the nature of the events that aren't working, I think there could be something wrong on the server side maybe. `"drop"` and `"dragenter"` are fully UI related events, while `"success"`, `"complete"` and `"addedfile"` have something to do with the server side.

Comment: @lechariotdor Nice one. Very nice thinking.

Comment: Great! This row has finished my work : var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

Comment: What is the 'arguments' variable? Where does it come from? I'm refering to the line `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`

Comment: @Gaboik1 The `arguments` object is an implicit local variable available within all (non-arrow) functions. It is useful when you don't know how many arguments to expect in a function, as you can (almost) use it like an array. More info on [MDN - Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Answer (score 13):

```
$("#dropzoneForm").dropzone({
    maxFiles: 2000,
    url: "../Uploader/HttpUploadHandler.ashx?param=" + result.prjID,
    success: function(file, response){
        //alert("Test1");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Does this help?

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
        thisDropzone = this;
        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
            var responseText = file.id // or however you would point to your assigned file ID here;
            console.log(responseText); // console should show the ID you pointed to
            // do stuff with file.id ...
        });
    }
};
```

For example, I have mine set up to attach the server path to the image name and pass this as a value into a form field on submit.  As long as you define responseText to point to the file ID you should get a return on this.

This link might be helpful as well: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/244

Comment: This was helpful! For the sake of ultra clarity I would like to mention that 'myDropzone' must be the camel-case version of your form's id.

Comment: this not works for me.
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                console.log(responseText); // console should show the ID you pointed to
                // do stuff with file.id ...
            });
        }
    };

Comment: You're replying to a solution offered almost 3 years ago.  It may be you have a different version of Dropzone than mine, or that your instance is not called "myDropzone" or any one of a number of things. Without posting your code, nobody can help you and your comment is not constructive.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    success: function(file, response){
        //alert(response);
        console.log(response);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
$(function() {
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone");
    myDropzone.on("success", function() {
        alert('Uploaded!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using jQuery and this is what worked for me:

```
var dz = $(".my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone()[0];
dz.dropzone.on("success", function (file, response) { ... }));
```

Note that the `dropzone()` method adds an `dropzone` attribute to the DOM object. You have to call `on()` on **that** object - not the jQuery `on()`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but I can't, since I have a low reputation.

For those of you who still have trouble retrieving the response from the server, if you're using chunking, Dropzone is hard-coding a blank response in this situation:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/caf200c13fd3608dd6bed122926d5848927f55b4/dist/dropzone.js#L2344

```
if (allFinished) {
    _this14.options.chunksUploaded(file, function () {
        _this14._finished(files, '', null);
     });
}
```

So retrieving the response doesn't seem to be supported for chunked uploads.