# dropzone.js redirect after success not working from json returned by php codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, dropzone.js

Im trying to redirect after upload success of my dropzone using $.getJSON from an echo json_encode from my controller but it seems like my javascript isn't actually getting the json_encode since i tried adding an alert inside the $.getJSON

here is my dropzone javascript

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
      url: "<?php echo(base_url('upload/image')); ?>",
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      autoDiscover: false,
      maxFilesize: 5,
      maxFiles: 1,
      acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif",
      previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
      clickable: "#dropzonePreview",
      accept: function(file, done) {
        console.log("uploaded");
        done();
      },
      init: function() {
          var myDropzone = this;
        //now we will submit the form when the button is clicked
            this.on("addedfile", function(file) { 
                $('.dz-message').hide();
                $('#dropzonenoimageerrormessage').hide();
            });
            this.on("reset", function(file) { 
                $('.dz-message').show();
            });
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
                this.removeAllFiles();
                this.addFile(file);
            });
        $("#sbmtbtn").on('click',function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($('#my-awesome-dropzone').valid() == true) {
                if (myDropzone.files.length) {
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                    // upload files and submit the form
                } else {
                    $('#dropzonenoimageerrormessage').show();
                }
            }
        });

      }, // init end
        success: function(file, response){
            $.getJSON("<?php echo(base_url('upload/image')); ?>", function(data){
                window.location = data.urllink;
            });
        }

    };
```

this is a segment of my controller that tries to send json

```
            if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile)){



                $newposturl = base_url('post/image/'.$data['recentlyuploadedimage']['slug']);

                $arr = array('urllink' => "$newposturl");

                echo json_encode($arr);


            }
```

the file does get moved and the data gets stored in the database but my javascript can't seem to get the json

Comment: The `success:` function should give you back the json from CI in the `response` variable. You don't need to use `$.getJSON`. [See this answer for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544006/3585500)

Comment: so does that mean i should remove remove `$.getJSON` and just use `windows.location = response.urllink;`?

Comment: @ourmandave oh it worked, thanks man! how do i make your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ourmandave gave the proper answer, I just needed to change this line of code

```
    success: function(file, response){
        $.getJSON("<?php echo(base_url('upload/image')); ?>", function(data){
            window.location = data.urllink;
        });
    }
```

remove the $.getJSON and use the response variable since the success function automatically gets the json response, so it'll look like this

```
    success: function(file, response){
            window.location = response.urllink;
    }
```